# How do I ensure my entire team has exactly the same version of the .Net runtime?

Tags: .net

My team is writing an ASP.Net webapp in VS2008 targeting .Net3.5 SP1. Some of us have the .Net runtime version `2.0.50727.3082` installed, and others have `2.0.50727.3053`. Everyone's Windows Update reports no available updates, even the people with the lower build number, and I wouldn't care at all except that all `.designer.cs` files include the runtime version in their header, and the differing runtime versions cause spurious changes in source control. Installing the very latest .Net3.5 setup from Microsoft doesn't address the issue - the .3053 version is still installed, even after the runtime is 'repaired'.

In the short term, how do I upgrade from .3053 to .3082, and in the medium term how do I ensure my entire team is on the same .Net runtime version?

Comment: As a point of note, this question is irrelevant in Studio 2010 since designer files are no longer marked with (useless) runtime version info.

Answer (score 5):

2.0.50727.3082 is the version of the .NET 2.0 runtime installed with .NET 3.5 sp1.  Make sure that all of your users correctly install .NET 3.5 SP1, and they should get that version.

*.3053 was installed with .NET 2.0 sp2's standalone install.  You could try uninstalling this, then installing 3.5sp1 again (since that installs its own version of .NET 2.0 sp2 - the one with the higher version number).

Comment: What is the correct way to install .NET 3.5 SP1, then?  Is there more to it than just downloading dotnetfx.exe from microsoft update and running it?

Comment: No - that will make it work.  Unfortunately, I think if you explicitly installed .NET 2.0 sp2, it "overwrites" the 2.0 version with the one you're seeing.  It came in 3.5sp1, so my guess is that they installed 2.0sp2 FIRST, then 3.5sp1, and the 3.5sp1 didn't see a need to update the 2.0 libs, since they were already there.  They are binary compatible, so there is not runtime issues - but it does cause weird behavior with source control.

Comment: I just tried the steps presented here - uninstalling .Net3.5SP1, uninstalling .Net2.0SP2, reinstalling .Net3.5SP1 - and what reappeared was .3053.

Answer (score 0):

You can build a Virtual Machine and install there all the tools your team needs to share then distribute it among your teammates.

Answer (score 0):

Reed's answer is good (+1), but the question also indicates the general need for some desktop standardization.  We use dev. images and then make official team posts regarding when and how to install updates.  Images are not always practical, so we have complete "getting started" documents for developers that ensure that they install only approved updates in a manner and order specified in the doc.  The system breaks down with consultants who generally want to use their own machines (laptops).  But, I've found that keeping environments as synchronized as possible cuts down a lot of "works on my machine" type issues and also cuts down on developer helping developer troubleshoot why things don't build or work correctly on their PC.

The downside is "one license all license" and I must have ReSharper, so everybody gets ReSharper. :)